# How to read and store 2 float values seperated by a comma from a file into two arrays where each float is stored in one array

Tags: c, file

my text file format is this:

3.2 , 5.6

444.2 , 555

112.34 , 32.3

---

i want to read the above information present within file name file.txt and store it in two arrays a,b where a will have the float value before the comma and b will have the float value after the comma

Comment: Read about [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) and [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), possibly about [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) in a loop to read each line. Then once you have the line, use [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) to scan out the two floating-point numbers, like so:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, myfile) != NULL)
{
  if(sscanf(line, "%f,%f", &a[i], &b[i]) == 2)
  {
    ++i;
  }
  else
    printf("Parse error in %s", line);
 }
```

Note that the return value from `sscanf()` says how many conversions that succeeded. If it isn't two, we don't want to move forward in the array. Remember to make sure `i` is initialized to `0` before the loop, of course.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted ... I forgot the `&`s in `sscanf()` initially, but that was fixed quite quickly.

Comment: can you please tell what is line here and why are we using it?

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DATA_SIZE 10

int main (void){
    char filename[256] = "file.txt";
    char input_line[128];
    FILE *fp;
    float a[DATA_SIZE],  b[DATA_SIZE];
    int i,j;

    if(NULL==(fp=fopen(filename, "r"))){
        perror("input file open");
        return -1;
    }
    i=0;
    while(NULL!=fgets(input_line, sizeof(input_line), fp)){
        if(*input_line == '\n') continue;
        a[i]=atof(strtok(input_line, " ,\n"));//ok even this ","
        b[i]=atof(strtok(NULL      , " ,\n"));
        ++i;
    }
    //check print
    for(j=0;j<i;++j){
        printf("a[%d]=%g, b[%d]=%g\n", j, a[j], j, b[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```